# How is it that ArcMap and QGIS produce feature classes with different numbers of points and different coordinates from the same TIFF?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, latitude-longitude, vectorization

I have a 300m by 300m B&W TIFF map of Brazil, and I need to convert all the pixel values into a point feature class. When I do it in ArcMap using Raster to Point, I get a feature class with 92,054,962 points. However, when I do it in QGIS using Raster Pixels to Points, I get a feature class with 92,054,882 points. The longitudes and latitudes of each point are also different between ArcMap and QGIS. Why is this happening even though the raster data is the same? Is it because QGIS and ArcMap use different algorithms?

It's important that I get consistent XY coordinates across all my TIFFs (which I will also convert to points), because I plan to join the TIFFs by longitude and latitude in R later.

Comment: Please add gdalinfo report of your image. Add also one pairs of coordinates that does not match, one from ArcMap and another from QGIS.

Comment: Generating one point feature per raster cell isn't the best possible model here. Converting to multipoint will significantly improve feature access time, but first I'd recommend an identity through a coarser fishnet, so that the dissolved multipoints only share values locally. For the Question you need to report image dimensions and nodata value count.